# SQl left outer join to fill null

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have joined two tables in SQL (see below) using a left outer join.

Is it possible to fill the null cells with other data?

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67178/1)

(from fiddle)

```
CREATE TABLE Data1
    (cost_type nvarchar(10), contract nvarchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO Data1
    (cost_type, contract)
VALUES
    ('LABR', 'contract1'),
    ('EQP', ''),
    ('RST', 'contract1')
;

CREATE TABLE data2
    (cost_type nvarchar(10), contract nvarchar(10), Name nvarchar(max))
;

INSERT INTO data2
    (cost_type,contract,Name)
VALUES
    ('LABR','contract1','John'),
    ('MAT','contract1','John'),
    ('EQP','','')
;
```

Query currently being run:

```
select * from data1 dt1 
left outer join data2 dt2 on dt1.cost_type=dt2.cost_type
```

The result I need is the following:

```
COST_TYPE  CONTRACT  NAME  
LABR, contract1, John  
EQP, contract1, John  
RST, contract1, John
```

This result is based on finding the most used value for the CONTRACT column and replacing all of the nulls with that value.  I need to do the same thing for the NAME column.

Comment: With which data? What is your expected result?

Comment: what you want to be instead of null value?

Comment: You would need to join the table once more, and join by the previous row

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Probably with the data referenced in the linked fiddle...

Comment: You people should not downvote on any question asked by new users. By doing this, you are discouraging  new users.

Comment: Vivek, it's not that he's new, it's that the question is poorly formatted and unclear.  The Fiddle is nice, but it'd be helpful if the question text included what specifically the OP was asking for; i.e. what "the data" is.

Comment: Initially i also thought of a downvote but after seeing his fiddle i was impressed and his question was understandable.

Comment: after doing outer join, in the empty column i want to to repeat "Contract 1" and in Name column i want to repeat "John"

Comment: @rockwell Since you're not ordering by anything, the order of the rows is random. If EQP would happen to end up on top, what value would you want? From another random row?

Comment: @rockwell: Why would you assume the EQP row should be contract1 and john?  This seems very odd considering the data you've supplied and could easily be screwed up badly.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson this is irrespective of the order,  i just want to have the Contract 1 in the contract column and John in the Name column

Comment: @rockwell: I think we need a little more context.  What else might be in that table?  How are you ensuring that the records *only* pertain to John and Contract 1?  Is it possible that John has a Contract 2 or that Contract 1 is also associated with Mary?  Will ALL records returned only have a single contract and Name value or will you expect multiple contract and name values to come back?  In the latter case, how would you pick which one applies to the blank values?

Comment: Is there some currently undefined relationship between EQP and the other records?  In other words how do we know EQP applies to John or Contract 1?

Comment: @ChrisLively,





Contract column has Contract1 and Name column has John  and they are not dependent, now i want to know if there is any way in sql will find the most used word in this case is contract1 for COntract column and replace all the null and empty cells with the most used value similar for Name column
</hr>

COST_TYPE| CONTRACT | NAME
LABR  | contract1 | John
EQP  |   |
RST  | contract1 | (null)
LABR  | contract1 | John
RST  | contract1 | (null)
LABR  | contract1 | John
LABR  | contract1 | John
LABR  | contract1 | John
LABR  | contract1 | John
LABR  | contract1 | John

Comment: @rockwell: thank you for providing the complete requirements.  I've updated your question so that it reflects all of the information necessary to answer it.  I know you are fairly new here, but please keep in mind that it helps to give all of the information necessary up front to solve the problem.  Otherwise a lot of us are just guessing.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: When you made it clear in the comments above that you wanted the values filled with the most used contracts/names, the query wasn't too complex to write; a CTE to find each the most usual contract/name, and a query that replaces empty values with the CTE values;

```
WITH most_used_contract AS (
  SELECT TOP 1 contract FROM Data1
  WHERE contract IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY contract
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
), most_used_name AS (
  SELECT TOP 1 name FROM Data2
  WHERE name IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY name
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
)
SELECT data1.cost_type, 
       CASE WHEN data1.contract IS NULL OR data1.contract = ''
            THEN muc.contract
            ELSE data1.contract END contract, 
       CASE WHEN data2.name IS NULL OR data2.name = ''
            THEN mun.name
            ELSE data2.name END name
FROM data1  
LEFT JOIN data2 ON data1.cost_type=data2.cost_type
LEFT JOIN most_used_contract muc ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN most_used_name mun ON 1=1
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/67178/9).

Comment: +1 for providing a very very specific answer to a problem that hasn't been well defined.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson this seems to good when you have hardcoded the value, but it there is Contract2 in Contract column then it wont repeat Contract2 all the way for all record similarly in case of john

Comment: @rockwell To quote you when asked about what to put in the columns if EQP is the first row; "i just want to have the Contract 1 in the contract column and John in the Name column". That is obviously not what you really mean then. What _would_ be the value if EQP came out the first row?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson if EQP is on the first row then the the contract column will have Contract 1 and Name as John