# SQL - using JOIN while filling missing values with NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

The most related question I looked into was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698106/sql-left-outer-join-to-fill-null) but sadly I did not get a solution for my problem there.

I have two tables, both have a similar column. The only difference is that one column is missing a few values. I want to join the tables, so that for the missing value in one column, the join will show the missing values.

Ill provide an example since this might be confusing -

```
table 1            table 2
ID count           ID count
1  9               1  2
2  2               2  1
3  1
```

I want the result to be

```
table 3
ID count2 count1
1  2      9
2  1      2
3  NULL   1
```

However, using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` I could only achieve the table "table 3" without the row for id 3, because it has no representation in table 2.

Can you help me with my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A left join would work for your sample data, I'm guessing you want to know what to do if you move the row with id 3 into table 2 so that your query will show all ids.  To show all rows from both tables, use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t1.id IS NULL THEN t2.id ELSE t1.id END AS id,
    t2.count as count2, t1.count as count1
FROM t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
```

Comment: you are a wizard! thank you very much, i used hours on this without knowing CASE or FULL are available for such a scenario.